# Find the prime-->sieve way

Tags: java, algorithm, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I tried it several times but still gives me ArrayOutOfIndex. But i want to save the memory so i use

```
boolean[]isPrime = new boolean [N/2+1];
```

instead of

```
boolean[]isPrime = new boolean [N+1];
```

This gives me ArrayOutOfIndex for line 23 and 47

line 23:

```
    for (int i = 3; i <= N; i=i+2) {
    isPrime[i] = true;
    }
```

line 47:

```
  for (int i = 3; i <= N; i=i+2) {
        if (isPrime[i]) primes++;
  ...
   }
```

---

```
Full code:

public class PrimeSieve {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java PrimeSieve N [-s(ilent)]");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        // initially assume all odd integers are prime

        boolean[]isPrime = new boolean [N/2+1];

        isPrime[2] = true;

        for (int i = 3; i <= N; i=i+2) {
            isPrime[i] = true;
        }

        int tripCount = 0;

        // mark non-primes <= N using Sieve of Eratosthenes
        for (int i = 3; i * i <= N; i=i+2) {

            // if i is prime, then mark multiples of i as nonprime
        if (isPrime[i]) {
          int j = i * i;
          while (j <= N){
            tripCount++;
            isPrime[j] = false;
            j = j + 2*i;
            }
                        }
                                            }

        System.out.println("Number of times in the inner loop: " + tripCount);

        // count and display primes
        int primes = 0;
        if(N >= 2 ){
            primes = 1;
        }
        for (int i = 3; i <= N; i=i+2) {
            if (isPrime[i]) primes++;
            if (args.length == 2 && args[1].equals("-s"))
                ; // do nothing
            else
                System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("The number of primes <= " + N + " is " + primes);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to save memory, using a bit-array instead of a `boolean[]` would save much more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store and access the array using the same indexing function: `isPrime[i/2]`

Answer (score 1):

When you change the size of your array from `[N+1]` to `[N/2+1]`, you need to also update the end-conditions of your for-loops. Right now your for-loops run until `i=N`, so you are trying to do `isPrime[i]` when `i > (N/2+1)` ... so you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Change this:

```
for (int i = 3; i <= N; i=i+2)
```

to this:

```
for (int i = 3; i <= N/2; i=i+2)
```

Comment: With the caveat that it should be strictly less than N/2+1 otherwise you get off by one IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: but this gives me the wrong answer instead....so weird... If i change all the N/2+1 back to N, it gives me the right answer..

Comment: @jzhong5 - Then your code is wrong. This is just keeps the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` from happening.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for example if N=50 your `isPrime`  only holds 26 elements, and you're trying to access the elements at 3,5..47,49 (which, of course, is out of bounds)

What you probably want is to use `i/2` (as the **index**) inside your loops, that way you are still iterating over the numbers 3,5..47,49, but you use the correct indexes of your vector.